# SerialDataReceived event doesn't fire (SerialPort setup for Arduino Clone)

Tags: c#, wpf, events, arduino, serial-port

this is my first question on here, since I couldn't find it answered anywhere.

I am not particularly new to WPF and C#, but I've never read SerialData with it before, and I'm having rudimentary problems I'm sure.

Setup:

Arduino clone (SparkFun Pro Micro) sending "Hello!" + a number to the USB serial port (COM5) once every second:

```
String hello = "hello!";
Serial.println(hello + i);
i++;
delay(1000);
```

And trying to receive it in WPF, with a simple button that refreshes the data to a TextBlock (tbData).

```
SerialPort sp = null;
String str = null;
int i = 0;

public MainWindow()
{
      InitializeComponent();
      sp = new SerialPort("COM5", 9600);
      sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(ReceiveData);
      sp.Open();
}


void ReceiveData(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
      str = sp.ReadLine();
}

private void Refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      tbData.Text = str;
}
```

But nothing happens, I seem to be getting an empty string, since the TextBlock doesn't show anything when I press the Refresh_Click button.

I can get it to work with a new Thread, but it keeps timeouting, and I read on here ([Timeouts in C# serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863881/timeouts-in-c-sharp-serial-port)) that the best (and simplest it seems) method is using a SerialDataReceived event.

```
t = new Thread(() =>
{
      int i = 0;
      while (run)
      {
            SerialString = sp.ReadLine();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
      }

      sp.Close();

});
```

What I am missing must be something along the lines of changing the size of the buffer? Or something similar?

Comment: Why do you need to sleep? You are calling ReadLine which is blocking and the sleep is doing nothing but delaying the results.  In the first method the program is terminating because you are not blocking.  Add a Console.ReadLine() to end of program to block after(sp.Open();)

Comment: The program is not terminating, it's just not showing anything in the textblock that I'm sending the string to, it's an WPF app. I seem to be reading an empty string and sending that to the textblock.

In the threading method, I just thought I didn't need to read the information more often than I was sending it to the port. If I remove Sleep(1000), the port still timeouts.

Comment: Is ReceiveData being called? you can check with a break-point. If it is being called, the problem may be that ReceiveData event runs on a different thread from the main thread so writing str on the SerialPort read thread may not update the value read on the main thread. You should put the reading/writing of str in a lock block or use BeginInvoke to update str. About the timeout, have you tried changing the SerialPort.ReadTimeout?

Comment: It seems it had to do with how the arduino sets up the communication (read answer below). Now it reports a problem that you are describing, with updating the textblock in another thread, so I guess I'll try beginInvoke for that! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've found the answer!

I am pretty clueless about Serial communications, but today I came across the MODE cmd function:

```
C:\Users\Username>mode

Status for device COM5:
-----------------------
    Baud:            9600
    Parity:          None
    Data Bits:       8
    Stop Bits:       1
    Timeout:         ON
    XON/XOFF:        OFF
    CTS handshaking: OFF
    DSR handshaking: OFF
    DSR sensitivity: OFF
    DTR circuit:     OFF
    RTS circuit:     OFF
```

And I noticed that it changed whenever I had the Arduino IDE report the data to me - which it would always do successfully! - and whenever I tried to make WPF do the same.
Above is the MODE return after I tried to run my own code, and:

```
Status for device COM5:
-----------------------
    Baud:            9600
    Parity:          None
    Data Bits:       8
    Stop Bits:       1
    Timeout:         OFF
    XON/XOFF:        OFF
    CTS handshaking: OFF
    DSR handshaking: OFF
    DSR sensitivity: OFF
    DTR circuit:     ON
    RTS circuit:     ON
```

this is what it showed after opening Tools>Serial monitor in the Arduino IDE, and closing it again immediately.

I changed my WPF code from:

```
sp = new SerialPort("COM5", 9600);
sp.Open();
```

to:

```
sp = new SerialPort("COM5", 9600);
//sp.ReadTimeout = 200;
sp.DtrEnable = true;
sp.RtsEnable = true;
sp.DataBits = 8;
sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
sp.Open();
```

And now both the threading example and the SerialDataReceived event runs smoothly (well, except I can't update a UI thread within a SerialDataReceived thread).

I hope someone out there finds this useful.